Expo React Native: printToFileAsync() on iOS sometimes freezes
I have an Expo React Native app which generates a PDF file from some HTML. This works fine on Android, but on iOS is extremely unreliable in that it sometimes generates it very quickly, other times it freezes the app for several minutes before it generates the PDF. Its a simple data table, no images. Drives me absolutely crazy.
Anyone know a workaround or how its supposed to work?
This either freezes for several minutes or works perfectly.
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    console.log("ios")
    const { uri } = await Print.printToFileAsync({ html });
    await shareAsync(uri, { UTI: '.pdf', mimeType: 'application/pdf' });
  } else if(Platform.OS === "android"){
    console.log("android")
    const { uri } = await Print.printToFileAsync({html, height:595, width:842, margins: {top: commonStyles.allPageMarginIOS, right: commonStyles.allPageMarginIOS, bottom: commonStyles.allPageMarginIOS, left: commonStyles.allPageMarginIOS}});
    const cUri = await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(uri)
    console.log('File has been saved to:', uri);
    await IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.VIEW', {
        data: cUri,
        flags: 1,
        type: 'application/pdf'
    });
  }   

I also tried the following (desperate) approach, but it gives the error

Possible undhandled promise rejection (id: 7): Error: Calling the "shareAsync" function hand failed -> Caused by: You don't have acces to the provided file

if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    console.log("ios")
    await shareAsync(html, { UTI: '.pdf', mimeType: 'application/pdf' });
  } else if(Platform.OS === "android"){
    console.log("android")
    const { uri } = await Print.printToFileAsync({html, height:595, width:842, margins: {top: commonStyles.allPageMarginIOS, right: commonStyles.allPageMarginIOS, bottom: commonStyles.allPageMarginIOS, left: commonStyles.allPageMarginIOS}});
    const cUri = await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(uri)
    console.log('File has been saved to:', uri);
    await IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.VIEW', {
        data: cUri,
        flags: 1,
        type: 'application/pdf'
    });
  }    

I am at a total loss here. Other functions that utilize shareAsync() work fine evne on iOS, it is only the PDF generation that is giving me trouble.
